# Get the hole selected object with kendo grid angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I want to get the object selected from a kendo grid and not only the id.

This is HTML :

```
<kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="gridData"
 [selectable]="true"
 kendoGridSelectBy="id"
 [selectedKeys]="scriptID" 
 (selectedKeysChange)="editHandler($event)"
 >
<kendo-grid-column field="product" title="PRODUCT"> </kendo-grid- 
 column>
<kendo-grid-column field="page" title="PAGE"> </kendo-grid- 
column>
<kendo-grid-column field="script" title="SCRIPT"> </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

In the typescript I got only the id :

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getAllScripts();
  }

getAllScripts(){
  this.scriptService.getAllRepairScripts().subscribe( data => {
    this.gridData = data;
  })
}
 editHandler($event){
  console.log($event) // $event contain the id 
  }
```

Can anyone help me how to recuperate the hole object and not only the ID ?

Comment: Im not familiar with Kendo angular, but what if you try this: `(selectedKeysChange)="editHandler(dataItem)"` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- Template -->  
 
<kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="data" [kendoGridSelectBy]="onSelectedKey" [(selectedKeys)]="kendoSelectedItems"   (selectedKeysChange)="onSelectedKeysChange($event)"  
[height]="300" scrollable="virtual" >   
</kendo-grid>  
 
// Component code  

import { RowArgs} from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid'; 

 
  public kendoSelectedItems = [];  
 
  public onSelectedKey(context: RowArgs): any {  
    return context.dataItem;  
  }  
 
  public onSelectedKeysChange(e) {  
    console.log(this.kendoSelectedItems);  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `selectionChange` event. It returns an object containing the unselected rows and selected rows whenever the selection changes. You get access to the `dataItem` of each row that was selected, which contains all the data. You can use it like this:

```
<!-- Template -->
<kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="gridData" [selectable]="{mode: 'single'}" (selectionChange)="selectionChangeHandler($event)">

</kendo-grid>


// Component code
public selectionChangeHandler(e) {
    if (e && e.selectedRows && e.selectedRows[0] && e.selectedRows[0].dataItem) {
        console.log("selectionChangeHandler", e.selectedRows[0].dataItem);
    }
}
```